# How to do a wave effect line in java?

Tags: java

I am doing a game like Geometry dash in java , I almost do all of the mechanics but I cant achieve wave effect , I try using a arrylist of lines then draw then in the points of my arrow , but it dint work or maybe I'm very confused

here is a capture of how look right now:

[image]

When I press X the arrow goes up and leave a diagonal trace (line) then if I released x its goes down I another line appear in the point of the last line , that whats is look like a wave effect of curves
here is a link of wave mechanic in geometry dash
[geometry dash wave effect][2]

Does I need to use sine wave? becaus its graph look pretty similar but I am not confident about that

I'm having a lot of problems with this mechanic and hope someone could helpe me with any idea and support

thanks for your idea i already solved it ! i finally get the wave effect c: , i draw the lines between the points of my arrow using a normal array 
[capture3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykJPe.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To increase your chance of getting a good answer soon, you could edit your question to improve its readability by removing the emoticons (`:c`), starting your sentences with uppercase letters, removing irrelevant parts (`hellow guys!`, `im having a lot of problems`) and explaining exactly what you want, what you tried and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store lines. Store points. Then draw lines between those points. At a minimum that'll stop it from breaking. Typically you're going shift those points to the left repeatedly at the same speed as the board gets shifted. You're just messing up the math, but, with points it'll at least make it very clear what you're actually getting wrong as well as keeping a contiguous set of lines.

It's not a sine wave or some bezier curves, it's a bunch of line segments as points for the previous position of your ship or whatnot changes.